# Get position of instance in geometry node

Tags: geometry, nodes, blender

I have a spline on this last and first points I put 2 Icosphere. I want to get there position

Get attributes.sample index. Curve to points with index section. And endpoints. I use blender 3.5 . Please help me. Thanks in advance